# What is the use case for a pointer to array of unknown size?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I recently realized that C++ allows pointers to arrays of unknown sizes, such as

```
int (*p)[];
```

The declaration above *is not* equivalent to `int* p;`. In fact, trying to use `p` to point to an array of fixed size results in a compile-time error, e.g.

```
int data[42];
p = data; // error, cannot convert int [42] to int (*) []
```

or

```
int* data;
p = data; // error, cannot convert int * to int (*) []
```

My question is when and why should we use such a pointer to an array of unknown size? Are there any compelling reasons to do so, and not to use simply `int*` instead?

**EDIT**

Such objects are not allowed as function parameters, see [Pointer to array of unspecified size "(*p)[]" illegal in C++ but legal in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27897646/3093378), but can nevertheless be declared in the program.

Comment: @MarcoA. That only talks about their (illegal) use as  function parameters, doesn't it? The construct itself seems still to be part of C++.

Comment: @MarcoA. Weirdest thing is that the declaring such a thing compiles with no warnings whatsoever, `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`, by both clang/gcc. And yes, they cannot be used as function parameters, but can nevertheless be defined. I made a note in the question, thanks for the link.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589449/what-is-flexarr-and-how-why-do-c-programmers-use-it

Comment: Ah here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24478830/1938163

Comment: @MarcoA. Thanks. Sorry, I thought it had been closed as a duplicate of the other one and reopened it before closing it again.

Comment: @MarcoA. thanks for digging in and finding the dupe. In terms of usability, I don't really find any compelling reasons to use such a construct though...

Comment: @Potatoswatter no problem at all! vsoftco I'd agree with you

Comment: @vsoftco I was going to add an answer that the current feature is basically a stub pending addition of a standard pointer conversion from "pointer to array of known bound" to "pointer to array of unknown bound." It's my bedtime, so I'll just leave it at that. There's a paper or defect report somewhere if you search hard enough.